# Relationships with obfuscated IDs

Tags: laravel, validation, hash, relationship, obfuscation

I have a problem with my app. I want to implement a complete ID's obfuscation to hide id's of every model. Is it a good idea?

I have implemented this wonderful [package](https://github.com/balping/laravel-hashslug) that gives me a simple trait with Hashing ID's and Route Model Binding <3

However, I'm having problems when developing tests... It's a bit annoying when I want to test, for example, a POST sending an ID, because I have to hash that ID before submit >.<

But my **big problem** is when client submit a form **with relationships**!

The form shows differents inputs, some of them are **select** that sets relationships, for example, a role_id. So the client sends:

```
{
    name: 'Username',
    email: 'mail@mail.com',
    role_id: 'Wtf10' // role_id is obfuscated :)
}
```

And that's all, the problem is in my controller, when validating and assignig the Role :(

```
public function store(UserRequest $request) // Problem 1 - Validation
{
    User::create($request->all()); // Problem 2 - Setting the correct role_id
}
```

So there are two problems. I do not figure out how to solve it fashionabily:

1. Problem 1 - Validation: I could create a [custom rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules). But well, aren't there a better approach? :D
2. Problem 2 - Relation: I could decode the hasehd ID, with something like `$role = Role::findIdBySlug($request->get('role_id'))->id` But omg, it will require me to apply this mechanism to every relationship input!?

So what's the correct way? Maybe a Big Master Middleware of Love that look for *every* obfuscated ID in request body and replace them with the decoded ID? :S

Help!

Thanks!

Comment: I think the conventional method is to use GUID's as opposed to ID's. You can just add a GUID column to your table, generate it, and then setup Route Model Binding on the guid. This seems to be a bit more work than is needed, too.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted public facing ids to be obfuscated without too much overhead.  No db changes, no custom route model binding resolution, etc.  So I build a package for it.  However, it was problematic to mess with 'id'.  So I add 'key' and hide 'id' in my json.  In my routes I can use an id or an obfuscated key interchangeably.  Priority middleware re-writes them on the way in so that laravel can work with normal ids internally.  I put out a public version of my package just now to try to help.

https://github.com/fuqu-io/laravel-ids2keys